# Dificuldade para usar variaveis entre funçoes

Tags: c

O meu problema é o seguinte: Tenho dificuldade para entender como posso declarar uma variável dentro de uma função e usa-la na int main(), o código a baixo é o exemplo disso, tentei de diversas formas e não obtive sucesso, se alguém puder me explicar como proceder ou corrigir o código agradeço desde já!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale.h>

struct dados{

        char nome[50];
        int idade;
        int telefone;
        char apelido[10];

     };

void coletaDados(struct dados *pInfo);

void limparTela();

void abertura();

void menuPrincipal(int cliente);

void clienteSim(int clientSim);

int main(){

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
int menu;

     struct dados info, *pInfo;
     pInfo = &info;


do{
    abertura();
    menuPrincipal(cliente);

    if(cliente == 1){
            clienteSim(clientSim);

    }

    else if(cliente == 2)
        coletaDados(&info);


}while(menu == 3);


return 0;
}

void abertura(){

printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t******************************\n");
printf("\t\t\t*****[Bem-Vindo ao banco]*****\n");
printf("\t\t\t**********[LOCKED]************\n");
printf("\t\t\t******************************\n");
Sleep(3000);
limparTela();
}

void menuPrincipal(int cliente){

int cliente;

printf("Para onde deseja prosseguir?\n\n");
printf("->[1]Já sou cliente\n");
printf("->[2]Não sou cliente\n\n");
printf("Digite o numero escolhido e pressione ENTER: ");
scanf("%d", &cliente);


}

void coletaDados(struct dados *pInfo){


     printf("Nome: ");
     scanf(" %[^\n]s", pInfo->nome);

     printf("Idade: ");
     scanf(" %d", pInfo->idade);

     printf("Telefone: ");
     scanf(" %d", pInfo->telefone);

     printf("Apelido: ");
     scanf(" %s", pInfo->apelido);

}
void clienteSim(int clientSim){

int clienteSim;

printf("Oque deseja fazer?\n\n");
printf("->[1]Checar saldo\n");
printf("->[2]Efetuar deposito\n");
printf("->[3]Efetuar saque\n\n");
printf("Digite o numero escolhido e pressione ENTER: ");
scanf("%d", &clienteSim);
}

void limparTela(){


COORD coord;
DWORD written;
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;

coord.X = 0;
coord.Y = 0;
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo ( GetStdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), &info );
FillConsoleOutputCharacter ( GetStdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), ' ',
info.dwSize.X * info.dwSize.Y, coord, &written );
SetConsoleCursorPosition ( GetStdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), coord );
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, um dos problemas do seu código é nessa função:

```
void menuPrincipal(int cliente) {
    int cliente;

    printf("Para onde deseja prosseguir?\n\n");
    printf("->[1]Já sou cliente\n");
    printf("->[2]Não sou cliente\n\n");
    printf("Digite o numero escolhido e pressione ENTER: ");
    scanf("%d", &cliente);
}
```

E na chamada dela:

`menuPrincipal(cliente);`

O que acontece é que na hora da chamada, você está passando a variável `cliente` como parâmetro, porém essa variável não existe nesse escopo. Ou seja, ela não está declarada na `main()`.

A maneira correta de declarar essa função seria algo assim:

```
int menuPrincipal() {
    int cliente;

    printf("Para onde deseja prosseguir?\n\n");
    printf("->[1]Já sou cliente\n");
    printf("->[2]Não sou cliente\n\n");
    printf("Digite o numero escolhido e pressione ENTER: ");
    scanf("%d", &cliente);

    return cliente;
}
```

Ou seja, a função agora retorna um inteiro (repare no `int` antes do nome da função). Sendo assim, na `main()` agora você pode chamá-la dessa forma:

`int cliente = menuPrincipal();`

Agora a variável `cliente` está sendo declarada e recebendo o valor que a função retorna.

O mesmo problema ocorre na função `clienteSim()` e na sua chamada.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 0):

Olha, nao entendi muito bem, copia na pergunta so as partes do codigo que vc está em duvida. Mas pela sua pergunta vc está em duvida referente ao escopo de variaveis. 
Existe o escopo global e o escopo local.

Uma variável declarada no escopo global é declarada fora de qualquer função e todas funções tem acesso a essas variáveis. Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Variavel_Global = 20; // como declarei fora de todas funçoes, essa variavel 
                         //pode ser acessada por qualquer funçao

void FuncaoQualquer(){

    printf("%d",Variavel_Global);

    }


int main() {
    printf("%d",Variavel_Global);
    FuncaoQualquer();

}
```

Nesse caso a Variável_Global é criada na memoria somente 1 vez e não é destruída, sendo possível vc acessa-la quando quiser em qualquer função.

Uma variável declarada em um escopo local, são as variáveis declaradas dentro de funções, essas variáveis são criadas apenas quando se entram na função e logo quando se sai daquela função a variável é destruída. Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void FuncaoQualquer();


int main()
{

    FuncaoQualquer(); //Entra na FunçaoQualquer

    printf("%d",Variavel_Local); // Nao vai funcionar pois a Variavel_Local ja foi destruida


}

void FuncaoQualquer(){

    int Variavel_Local = 20; // Aqui Variavel_Local foi criada

    printf("%d",Variavel_Local); // esse print funciona pq eu ainda estou dentro da FuncaoQualquer

    // aqui a funçao acaba e antes de retornar para a main o sistema destroi a Variavel_Local

}
```

Se vc deseja utilizar o valor de uma variável criada em outra função na sua main vc deve retornar o valor ou usar um ponteiro para uma variável que já foi criada em sua main.

Exemplo retornando o valor:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int FuncaoQualquer(); //FuncaoQualquer agora é do tipo int pois vai retornar um inteiro


int main()
{
    int Recebe_Valor_Retornado;

    Recebe_Valor_Retornado = FuncaoQualquer(); 
    // o valor retornado por FuncaoQualquer vai ser armazenado na variavel Recebe_Valor_Retornado

    printf("%d",Recebe_Valor_Retornado);


}

int FuncaoQualquer(){

    int Variavel_Local = 20; // Aqui Variavel_Local foi criada

    return Variavel_Local; // aqui eu retorno para minha main somente o valor de Variavel_Local
                            // e logo apos VariavelLocal é destruida


}
```

Exemplo usando ponteiro:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void FuncaoQualquer(int *Ponteiro); 
//FuncaoQualquer pode ser void pois ela nao retorna nada, mas agora ela deve receber um ponteiro


int main()
{
    int Valor;

    int  *Ponteiro_Para_Valor = &Valor; 
    // Aqui criei um ponteiro que aponta para o endereço de memoria da variavel Valor

    FuncaoQualquer(Ponteiro_Para_Valor); 
    // aqui chamo FuncaoQualquer e mando o nosso ponteiro Ponteiro_Para_Valor

    printf("%d",Valor);


}

void FuncaoQualquer(int *Ponteiro){

    int Variavel_Local = 20; // Aqui Variavel_Local foi criada

    *Ponteiro = Variavel_Local; // Aqui eu jogo somente o valor de Variavel_Local
    //Diretamente no espaço de memoria que eu reservei para a variavel Valor lá na minha main
    // e logo apos VariavelLocal é destruida


}
```

Como vc está usando struct eu indico que vc crie um ponteiro para toda a struct, e passe o ponteiro como argumento para suas funçoes, assim as funçoes nao precisam retornar nada, e os dados sao escritos normalmente na struct atravez do ponteiro.
Agora se vc estiver trabalhando com Listas Estaticas em estrutura de dados onde vc deve alocar a quantidade exata de memoria para um elemento da sua struct. Seria dessa forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Struct dos dados
struct Aluno
{
    int matricula;
    char nome[30];
    float n1,n2,n3;
};

//Struct da lista
struct ListaEstatica
{
    int quantidade; //quantas posiçoes ja ocupei
    Aluno dados[100];
};

//Funçao que cria as listas
ListaEstatica* CriarListaEstatica(){ //funçao que ira retornar um ponteiro de ListaEstatica
    ListaEstatica *NovaListaSendoCriada; //o ponteiro que vou retornar
    NovaListaSendoCriada = (ListaEstatica *) malloc(sizeof(ListaEstatica)); //alocando espaço na memoria do tamanho exato 
    if(NovaListaSendoCriada != NULL){  //se minha lista nao ésta null é pq criou de boa
        NovaListaSendoCriada->quantidade = 0; // a quantidade de dados na minha lista é 0
        return(NovaListaSendoCriada); // retorno o ponteiro que aponta para a lista que criei
    }else // se nao for diferente de null nao criou a lista de boas
    {
        printf("Deu pau, nao criou a lista");
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{

printf("Bem Vindo A lista Estatica: \n");
ListaEstatica *MeusDados = CriarListaEstatica(); 
//criei um ponteiro do tipo ListaEstatica e ele vai receber a lista criada e retornada por CriarListaEstatica
 strcpy(MeusDados->dados[0].nome, "Jose"); 

 //agora posso adicionar dados na minha lista que foi criada dentro de outra funçao
 MeusDados->dados[0].matricula = 85102018;
 MeusDados->dados[0].n1 = 10;
 MeusDados->dados[0].n2 = 5;
 MeusDados->dados[0].n3 = 9;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!